# Fade in/out for url

Tags: jquery, html

I want to fade in/out a url when i pass the cursor on a Div. I made a simple example in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Ppbm/60/ .

```
$('.lnkDiv:visible').fadeOut();
var timer;

$('.contDiv:visible').on({
        mouseover: function () {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $('.lnkDiv:visible').fadeIn();
        },
        mouseout : function () {
            timer = setTimeout(function () { 
                $('.lnkDiv:visible').fadeOut();
            }, 100);
        }
    });
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?
http://jsfiddle.net/daKGN/1/

```
$('.lnkDiv:visible').fadeOut();
var timer;

$('.contDiv:visible').on({
        mouseover: function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $('.lnkDiv').fadeIn();
    },
    mouseout : function () {
        timer = setTimeout(function () { 
            $('.lnkDiv').fadeOut();
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

`<img>` tags should be written as `<img />` and not `<img></img>`. Also the `.contDiv` had no height when the `<a>` was hidden, and your jQuery selectors all contained `:visible` even when the `<a>` was hidden.